# How do I increment an integer in an URL?

Tags: bash, scripting, curl

I want to scrape a forum by using an API and curl.

API:

> https://api.hackertarget.com/pagelinks/?q=websitetotest.com

Here is the initial link:

> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=840124.0

Desired outcome:

> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=840124.20

I need to be able to do this all the way up to 4,240

> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=840124.4240

As you can see, the only integer that changes is after the dot.

Answer (score 3):

Curl, if that's what you want to use to access the URLs, supports URLs with ranges:

```
curl ... 'https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=840124.[0-4240]'
```

Where `...` are other options that you may want to use.

The range syntax also allows for stepping with another increment than 1.  For example, to get every 20th URL:

```
curl ... 'https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=840124.[0-4240:20]'
```

For further information, please refer to the `curl` manual.

To generate a list of URL for *separate* processing with `curl` or some other program, consider using a brace expansion (if your shell supports it):

```
printf '%s\n' 'https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=840124.'{0..4240}
```

With `bash` and some other shells, an increment may be used as in `'...URL...'{0..4240..20}`.

The list could then be piped to e.g. `xargs` that could invoke your `curl` or other program with the URLs as arguments.